# import static files using Webpack with copy-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

My current Webpack version is `3.10.0` Copy-webpack-plugin version is `4.3.1` This is my configuration file `plugin` parts in webpack.

```
 plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: APP_DIR + '/static' } ]),
],
```

Here APP_DIR is the path to my client folder.

In my static folder I have `SOME_FILE.js` which is a file that simply exports an array of objects. The size of that file is 700kb. I don't want to include that in my code so that my Webpack bundles it and increases my app size. I want to include that static file separately.

So when I run this command

```
import COUNTRIES from 'static-path/SOME_FILE.js';
```

But this gives me an error

```
 Module not found: Error:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who runs into a similar situation/problem. I solved it using a request method like `fetch` or `axios`. (I used fetch). So the JSON was put in a static folder and using fetch I loaded the JSON file.

I did some research on it, turns out there is a second option as well. Using the common chunks plugin in `webpack`. Webpack has a detail documentation regarding code splitting [Code Splitting In Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/code-splitting)

I personally went for the first option. It seemed easy and kind of does the same thing as option 2, but only in a simpler way.